# repeating input outside main loop

Tags: c, loops

i'm tasked with a problem that's needed me to print a statement according to the amount of prime numbers in a certain range.This is what i got so far

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    //control
    int j,i,t,n,x,no=0;
    //init
    int num[100],factor,temp; 


    scanf("%d", &t);      //sets up parameter/cases first
    scanf("%d", &num[i]); //the problem


    for(i=0; i<t; i++){
        printf("Case #%d: \n", ++no);
        //printf("%d ", num[i]);
        for(n=0; n<num[i]; ){               
            for(x=1; x<num[i]; x++){
                if(num[i] % x == 0)
                    factor = x;
            }
            if(factor > 1 || num[i] == 1){
            }
            else{
                printf("I will become a good boy\n");
            }
            num[i]--;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the program runs correctly but i need it to have the user input all the needed value **THEN** output the statement(s). I did put the input statement inside the main loop although the end result would be:

> input output input output

instead of

> input input output output

Comment: Hint: what's the value of `i` when you do `scanf("%d", &num[i]);` ?

Answer (score 3):

Just add a loop to read in all the values before the output loop

```
for(i=0; i<t; i++){
    scanf("%d", &num[i]);
}
```